# No effect of colorkey.space attribute in lattice's levelplot function

Tags: r, lattice, levelplot

I try to draw the color key on the left side, but when adding the attribute `colorkey.space="left"` to the levelplot function, the color key does not move at all but is still on the right (default) side. Anyone knows if this is a bug, or am I missing something?

Here is a excerpt from the help function of levelplot:

> colorkey -     logical specifying whether a color key is to be drawn
>   alongside the plot, or a list describing the color key. The list may
>   contain the following components:
>
> space: location of the colorkey, can be one of "left", "right", "top"
>   and "bottom". Defaults to "right".

Note: `colorkey=FALSE` works perfectly fine

Comment: Just from reading that help excerpt, it looks like you'd at least need `colorkey=list(space="left")`. For any help beyond that, it's probably better if you post a reproducible example of your plotting code.

Answer (score 2):

The wording implies you need to pass a `list` with components such as space

eg

```
 colorkey = list(space = 'left')
```

Using a modification example from `?levelplot`

```
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
          colorkey = list(space = 'left')
```

[image]

Comment: @bluewoodtree -- Since this solved the problem, then perhaps "accept" the answer?